# Docker and bower links

Tags: nginx, docker, bower

I'm using docker to run a simple static web project, using the nginx official image. As a bower dependence I have a ui lib that is mine and is shared among two of my projects. To facilitate the development process I created a volume to my local machine to serve local files through the /html folder inside the nginx container. It works fine this way.

But, if I try to use *bower link* to create a link between a local copy of my ui lib and the bower dependence the nginx web server is not able to find the folder, since the link points to my local machine.

I'm running the docker vm in a Mac.

Did someone experienced something similar and have an idea about how to solve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I just run into this issue and found a way to solve it nicely.

The problem is that when you mount as a volume the whole /html folder the symlinks created by bower link are copied into your container but not the actual folders they are pointing at. **When nginx tries to serve the file, it follows the symlink but now INSIDE the container, where the route is invalid.**

To fix this, create another volume that maps the symlink directly. **This way, docker-compose will follow the symlink BEFORE mounting into the container, therefore copying the actual folder contents**. The nice thing about this is that in your local file system you still have the folder and the symlink working, so you can work as usually :)

Practical example:
My folder structure

```
/app
|--/bower_components
   |--/packageA
   |--/packageB -> symlink to /foo/bar/packageB
```

My compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
   volumes:
     - .:/foo
     - ./bower_components/packageB:/foo/bower_components/packageB
 ...
```

Let me know if it worked, cheers!